# MAO card game in C++

Tags: c++

So I wanted to program a card game that is called Mao. In this game players are given a first card with a letter A, B, C or D and a number from 1 to 9. They have to put another cards which they have but they must be the same letter or the same number. For example if the first card is A7, players can but A8, D7 and so on. But they can't put C3. In my program, the user inputs a first card that is called 'first' and then he inputs other cards named 'second'. If the user can use one of the cards followed by the rules of the game, program should return 'Yes'.If not, then 'No'. My code is:

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string first = "";
string second = "";
cout<<"enter first card: "<<endl;
cin>>first;
for (int i = 0 ;i < 5 ;i++)
{
    cin>>second;
    
    
}
for (int i = 0; i < 5 ;i++)
{
    if (second[0]==first[0] || second[1]==first[1])
    {
        cout<<"Yes"<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"no"<<endl;
    }
}
return 0;

}
```

The output should be like this:

```
enter first card:
A7
A9
C1
B7
D7
D5
Yes
no
Yes
Yes
no
```

But it only displays 'Yes'. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: The first loop is overwriting the value in `second` before the second loop runs.

Comment: So what should I change?

Comment: Probably move that brace down a few lines

Comment: Actually, what you should do is use an array or `std::vector`, and adjust the logic accordingly. You should always follow The Golden Rule Of Computer Programming: "your computer always does exactly what you tell it to do, instead of what you want it to do". You told your computer to read input five times, and each time save the value in the same variable. Then do everything else five times again, using the same value. So that's what your computer does, with this program. If you want your computer to do something else, simply tell your computer what it should do, that's all.

Comment: Thank you @SamVarshavchik I used an array and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
string first="";
string second[5];
cout<<"Enter first card: "<<endl;
cin>>first;
for (int i=0; i<5;i++)
{
    cin>>second[i];
}
cout<<"------------------------"<<endl;
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    if (second[i][0]==first[0] || second[i][1]==first[1])
    {
        cout<<"Yes"<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"No"<<endl;
    }
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).